# C# WPF DataContext and unsuccessful binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, datagrid

I am using a DataGrid inside a Usercontrol and am trying to bind it to my ObservalbeCollection in ViewModel.

I tried so many things, but the data is not showing in DataGrid when added, only headers.

*ObservavleCollection* is of "LogItem" type:

```
namespace Gui
{
    public class LogItem
    {
        public String Type { get; set; }
        public String Message { get; set; }

        public LogItem(string Type, string Message)
        {
            this.Type = Type;
            this.Message = Message;
        }
    }
}
```

*ViewNodel*, containing the ObservavleCollection.

```
namespace Gui.vm
{
    public class LogVm:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        #region properties
        private ObservableCollection<LogItem> logsCollection;
        public ObservableCollection<LogItem> LogsCollection
        {
            get { return this.logsCollection; }
            set => throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        #endregion

        #region members
        private LogModel model;
        #endregion

        public LogVm()
        {
            Debug.Print("in logVm ctor");
            this.model = new LogModel();
            this.logsCollection = new ObservableCollection<LogItem>
            {
                // For testing
                new LogItem("INFO", "bla"),
                new LogItem("INFO", "bla"),
                new LogItem("INFO", "bla"),
                new LogItem("INFO", "bla")
            };
        }
    }
}
```

File *Log.xaml.cs*, where I initialize DataContext to be LogVm

```
namespace Gui.views
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Log.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Log : UserControl
    {
        public Log()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new LogVm();
        }
}
}
```

File *Log.xaml*

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="Gui.views.Log"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Gui.vm"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             xmlns:diag="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase"
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
             >

    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="dgrid" ItemsSource="{ Binding LogsCollection , diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=Low}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">

            <DataGrid.Columns>

                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type" Width="1*" Binding="{Binding Type ,  diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}">
                </DataGridTextColumn>

                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Message" Width="9*" Binding="{Binding Message ,  diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=Low}">
                </DataGridTextColumn>

            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

I added the following line to XAML, for diagnosing.

```
xmlns:diag="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase"
```

from line 6. DataContext appears as null repeatedly, even though I set it to be the LogVm in code.

I tried to flip order of initializeComponents() and data context assignment, but it causes to binding to deactivate.

```
'Gui.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Gui.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\mscorlib.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_he_b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.resources.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'Gui.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Gui.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework.Aero2\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationFramework.Aero2.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
System.Windows.Data Warning: 62 : BindingExpression (hash=64879470): Attach to System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.ItemsSource (hash=7358688)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=64879470): Resolving source
System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=64879470): Found data context element: DataGrid (hash=7358688) (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 71 : BindingExpression (hash=64879470): DataContext is null
System.Windows.Data Warning: 65 : BindingExpression (hash=64879470): Resolve source deferred
'Gui.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Gui.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_he_31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationFramework.resources.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
in logVm ctor
in logModel ctor
in logModel ctor AGAIN
'Gui.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Gui.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework-SystemXml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\PresentationFramework-SystemXml.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Gui.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Gui.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\UIAutomationTypes\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\UIAutomationTypes.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Gui.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Gui.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationCore.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_he_31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationCore.resources.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=64879470): Resolving source
System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=64879470): Found data context element: DataGrid (hash=7358688) (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 71 : BindingExpression (hash=64879470): DataContext is null
'Gui.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Gui.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework-SystemCore\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\PresentationFramework-SystemCore.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Log' property not found on 'object' ''MainWindow' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=Log; DataItem='MainWindow' (Name=''); target element is 'Log' (Name=''); target property is 'DataContext' (type 'Object')
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=64879470): Resolving source
System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=64879470): Found data context element: DataGrid (hash=7358688) (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 71 : BindingExpression (hash=64879470): DataContext is null
'Gui.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Gui.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\avn\AppData\Local\Temp\VisualStudio.XamlDiagnostics.14340\Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WpfTap.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Gui.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Gui.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Gui.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Gui.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\SMDiagnostics\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\SMDiagnostics.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Gui.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Gui.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Internals\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=64879470): Resolving source
System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=64879470): Found data context element: DataGrid (hash=7358688) (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 71 : BindingExpression (hash=64879470): DataContext is null
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=64879470): Resolving source
System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=64879470): Found data context element: DataGrid (hash=7358688) (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 71 : BindingExpression (hash=64879470): DataContext is null
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=64879470): Resolving source  (last chance)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=64879470): Found data context element: DataGrid (hash=7358688) (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 78 : BindingExpression (hash=64879470): Activate with root item <null>
'Gui.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Gui.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_he_b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.resources.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'Gui.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Gui.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\UIAutomationProvider\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\UIAutomationProvider.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
The program '[14340] Gui.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

I am trying to figure out what's wrong here for a really long time.

Comment: Without testing this try setting binding mode to oneway because you have it throwing an exception in the setter for LogsCollection.

Comment: added, but not relataed to the binding failure.

Comment: Wasn't sure and figured you'd see that exception but worth adding since you have that exception anyway.

Comment: Have you tried placing this.DataContext = new LogVm(); before  InitializeComponent();?

Comment: @Firas I tried, even wrote it in question. It causes to binding to deactivate, And nothing is showing.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to call onPropertyChanged() in the setter of the property you want to change from GUI. In you case - ObservableCollection.

But the main problem I think is that when you define columns in XAML you should use fieldName, so you can try this:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Type" Width="1*" FieldName="Type">
```

Answer (score -1):

Two way binding can help:

```
Binding="{Binding Type , Mode=TwoWay}
```

Comment: Tried it before and it doesn't help.